# Twitter Retweet count of a Tweet

Tags: asp.net, twitter, tweets

I want to get count of all Retweets for a specific Tweet from Twitter. I used Twitterizer

Comment: What specific error do you have in your code?

Comment: no error, just need the way to implement it

Comment: @Numenor He didn't mention about errors, he's asking a way to do it via Twitterizer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `RetweetCount` property in Twitterizer. http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/P_Twitterizer_TwitterStatus_RetweetCount.htm

in C# it would be like:

```
TwitterStatus Tweet;
Tweet.Id = '2134213'; //set the twitter ID
MessageBox.Show(Tweet.RetweetCount);
```

Comment: I know this function but how to use it?

Comment: I updated my answer, I havent tested it yet but its how it should work.

Comment: I don't have tweet id, I want to give tweet as text.

Answer (score 0):

Ruel is on the right track, but a little off.

The code (in the latest version: 2.3) would look like this:

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> statusResponse = TwitterStatus.Show(123456);
int RetweetsOfThatStatus = statusResponse.ResponseObject.RetweetCount;
```

Feel free to ask any additional questions on the forums. I usually answer questions there throughout the day.

Ricky
Twitterizer's Architect/Developer

Comment: I don't have tweet id, I want to give tweet as text.

Comment: You're trying to supply the text of a tweet and found out how many times that text has been tweeted?

There is nothing built into the Twitter API (and therefore into Twitterizer) that could perform this exactly. The closest thing you could do is use the Search API to search for the text, page through the result, and count them as you go. Since you're not looking at a specific tweet (by ID) this wouldn't only be proper 'retweets' and would include false positives and omit any variations in the text.

Answer (score 0):

@hotcode: I don't think that any twitter client api is providing that feature for you. but you can try to search for:

RT @user: text

on twitter and then parse the results if it is really a retweet of your intented tweet. If that doesn't work on twitter you can use this [here](http://jetwick.com?q=java&sort=retweets)